# Smallest integer greater than or equal to another integer but with prime factors less than or equal to 7

Tags: prime-numbers, fast-fourier-transform

More clearly stated than title, let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A = \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m \geq n \text{ and } m = 2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d \text{ for some } a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Find $\min(A)$. This can be brute force calculated in $\prod_{k=2,3,5,7} \log_k(n)$ calculations in a "quadruply nested" for loop, since you know that the values for $a, b, c, d$ can never exceed $\log_2(n), \log_3(n), \log_5(n), \log_7(n)$ respectively. Can this complexity be improved or is it optimal? The context of this is for optimization of memory allocations for FFT.

A thought that **does not work** follows. Compute the prime factorization of $n$ and split as $n = 2^w 3^x 5^y 7^z \cdot q$ where $q$ is the "rest" of the factorization with larger primes. Then somehow take the factorization of $q$ to recursively solve the same problem and use those results. However, this does not seem to work for $n = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$. The correct answer is $150$ for the $q$ part of $11 \cdot 13 = 143$. My idea doesn't work because the answer to the same problem of "find $\min(A)$" for the case $n = 11$ is $m = 12$ and similary for $n=13$ is $14$. Then $12\cdot 14 = 168 > 150$ and so this doesn't work. Basically then $11 \cdot 13$ would have to be its own base case in recursion, and my guess is that you'd never get a true base case and that this approach just straight up does not work.

Comment: The inequality is equivalent to $a\log2+b\log3+c\log5+d\log7\ge\log n$, which is an integer (linear) programming problem; [techniques for solving them](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/ilp.pdf) (they're not always trivial) have been well studied.

Comment: What are typical values for $n$?  Existing prime search and prime factorization routines are very fast, so for $n < 10^6$ or so this shouldn't take more than a few seconds on a laptop.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork nevertheless , factoring each number until we get a solution will be far from the optimal approach. Maybe , for $n\approx 10^6$ it does not really matter , but for $n\approx 10^{12}$, the program will become too slow. Greg Martin's approach is easy and very efficient for larger $n$. And even if we apply brute force, there should be methods more efficient to check whether the largest prime factor is $7$ or less.

Comment: If $n$ is relatively small, Greg Martin's approach can even be applied with brute force and won't take much time. Even $n\approx 10^{30}$ should not be very problematic with this approach.

Comment: This isn't an interesting solution, but why not pre-compute the 7-smooth integers (numbers of the form $2^a 3^b 5^c 7^d$)?  For example there are only 10000 such integers up to 63221760000 (see https://oeis.org/A002473).

Comment: Here's the same question from StackOverflow, but with prime factors less than or equal to 5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242733/find-the-smallest-regular-number-that-is-not-less-than-n

Comment: @Peter.  Good points.. but they're moot if $n \sim 10^6$.  I wonder why the OP won't answer that very basic question?

Comment: @MichaelLugo This is surely the best method, if $n$ has a moderate magnitude.

Comment: OK... but *does* $n$ have a moderate magnitude??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In fact, this has still not been clarified by the author.

Comment: Additionally : The title rules out equality, the body not. This should also be clairified.

Comment: Yes, practically speaking $n$ is relatively small ($\sim 10^{5}$), and brute force is sufficient for my purposes. It was more out of curiosity if you could do better than brute force. Linear programming seems to be a nice solution to the problem proposed by Greg Martin. Equality is allowed. I have edited the title to say "greater than or equal to." Sorry about that.

Comment: Just a note: $143 < 144 = 2^{4}3^{2} < 150$.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in (log n)^2 log log n operations.

Find all products $2^a \cdot 7^d$ up to and including the first one that is ≥ n, and sort them in ascending order to form a sequence $x_i$.

Find all products $3^b \cdot 5^c$ up to and including the first one that is ≥ n, and sort them in descending order to form a sequence $y_i$.

The product you are looking for is some $x_i$, multiplied by the last $y_j$ that makes the product ≥ n. You start with j = 1 and i = 1 and check $x_i y_j$. As long as that product is ≥ n then it might be the smallest product ≥ m, and you increase j. Then as long as the product is < n you increase i by 1 until you have another product ≥ n. You finish when all numbers are processed.

Most operations are performed (log n)^2 times, except the sorting adds a factor log log n. You don't need to store (log n)^2 numbers if you generate the lists $x_i$ and $y_j$ on the fly.

Similar schemes can be used often to handle 2k lists using k loops.